# How to close a modal by clicking outside the modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

In a very simple jQuery modal, I close the modal by clicking on CLOSE as

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#overlay, #alertModalOuter').fadeOut(400, function() {
     $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

How can I close the modal by clicking whether on CLOSE button (which is inside the modal windows) OR clicking anywhere outside the modal window.

Comment: bind the same on the `#overlay` element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing your function like so should work:

```
    $('#close, #overlay').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#overlay, #alertModalOuter').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $('#close').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You made a mistake "#close #overlay" means element with id #close followed by element with id #overflow, you meant "#close, #overlay"

Answer (score 5):

I found it helpful to include:

```
$('.item-modal').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the same click listener to your overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question pertains to jQuery, but here's how I did this in Vue on my modal component in case anyone finds it helpful. My modal HTML is basically lifted directly from this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

I set two `@click` attributes, one on the outermost modal element (`modal-mask`) that calls my `close()` method (which emits the `close` event to the parent component) and one on the actual modal window element (`modal-container`) that with the `.stop` event modifier (`@click.stop`) to stop the click from bubbling up to the parent element (`modal-mask`). Works like a charm.