# How to use jquery to close the modal window in the w3schools example when user clicks outside of modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

link :
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2

existing code:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

changed as per Jquery:

```
$(window).on('click', function(event){
    if(event.target == $('#myModal')){
        $('#myModal').css({display: "none"});
    }
});
```

event is firing, but if condition is not passing.
Can you suggest the way to do it.

It seems a same question about closing modal, but my question asked about closing the modal window when user clicked on outside area of modal. [How to close a modal by clicking outside the modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152819) contains about closing modal window when user clicks on close button. Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close a modal by clicking outside the modal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152819/how-to-close-a-modal-by-clicking-outside-the-modal-window)

Comment: I am new to UI development, i am implementing it in jquery by seeing w3schools example. But getting stucked while closing modal when we give a click in outside area of modal window. Remaining everything I implemented. I tried to get from your link but it seems different to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to match `id` instead of whole object like,

```
$(window).on('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.id == 'myModal'){
        $('#myModal').css({display: "none"});
    }
});
```

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
/*window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}*/
$(window).on('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.id == 'myModal'){
        $('#myModal').css({display: "none"});
    }
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please i am getting answer by using function

```
$(window).on('click', function(event){
if(event.target.nodeName != 'BUTTON'
&& $('#myModal').css('display') == "block"){
    $('#myModal').css({display: "none"});
}
});
```